# Reducing Memory Use on OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm using an opengl es based framework to create my game.I have an out of memory problem on some devices.I have 15 textures with a size 1024x1024(totally 10 mb).On memory they covers a lot of space.Some devices are exiting from game on loading time

I want to reduce memory use and how can i do that?Maybe a solution when i loading bitmaps into memory will be great.That's my texture class:[Texture.java](http://code.google.com/p/beginning-android-games/source/browse/trunk/ch09-jumper/src/com/badlogic/androidgames/framework/gl/Texture.java)

Comment: Can you use compressed textures?

Comment: @Tetrad How can i use them?You mean some compressed texture formats like PVR-TC?Or an optimization on bitmaps?

Comment: I mean PVR compressed textures.  Those are compressed in-memory.

Comment: @Tetrad Okey but only specific devices are supporting PVR compressed textures.How can i do that with all devices?

Comment: @droidmachine ETC texture compression is supported on all Android devices with OS version 2.3 and newer. The downside is that ETC doesn't support alpha channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Texture compression it is. Here is a link explaining with example code snippet:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148795/android-opengl-texture-compression

Comment: Okey but some devices are supporting that compression types.How can i achive them in all devices?

Comment: the link suggests u create a fallback if texture compression isnt supported. My suggestion is to store backup 256x256 or 512x512 of each image. That would make your app bigger tho, so i suggest you resize the 1024x1024 images after loading them instead. this should help: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2009/12/25/resizing-a-bitmap/